# Show cursor on two text box at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two text boxes like,

```
<input type="text" id="left" />
<input type="text" id="right" />
```

Is it possible to focus these two text boxes at the same time?
I don't know how it possible.I need to show cursor in these two text boxes at the same time.
if i focus #left ,#right lost its focus.

Note : **I am trying to create a side by side web application.shows two same views on single web page.**

***I know how to show the same values,I need to show the cursor blinking on two inputs.***

Comment: No, you can't. Only one input can have focus at the time.

Comment: After this if you type anything , it will be for the both. why not you just bind each other.? onchange #left affect goes to #right and vice-versa.

Comment: @Rishi I am creating a side by side design.shows clone two views

Comment: is it possible to show a fake cursor using css or something like?

Comment: Not using CSS, but you can always create a div with the image of a cursor in the background and move it with Javascript, following the mousemove() event of the original cursor to move your div on the page.

Comment: @JulienD I think he meant text cursor, not mouse pointer

Comment: @JulienD You are correct

Comment: The only options is to implement your own input with blinking cursor that will look like the native one.

Comment: This is not for web.here i have no mouse

Comment: @JulienD Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 2):

Try doing something like this...Every time the left input is changed the right one's value is change too.

```js
$("#left").on("input",function() {
  $("#right").val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="left" />
<input type="text" id="right" />
```

Comment: I know how to show the same values,I need to show the cursor blinking on two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to clone your input, you can simply do this by adding an `oninput` attribute like:

```
<input type="text" id="left" name="left" oninput="right.value = left.value; return true;" />
<input type="text" id="right" name="right" oninput="left.value = right.value; return true;" />
```

No jQuery needed. Customize it the way you want it. Here's a fiddle:

```html
<input type="text" id="left" name="left" oninput="right.value = left.value; return true;" />
<input type="text" id="right" name="right" oninput="left.value = right.value; return true;" />
```

Comment: I know how to show the same values,I need to show the cursor blinking on two inputs.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and you really shouldn't...
That's like asking you to read a book while watching TV.

However, that sort of thing, might be possible on multi-user & multi-touch OS machines. That is, two users on the same machine can work two different tasks simultaneously on the same surface. But that's military. And even than, one user, can only have one input focus at a time.

Answer (score 1):

you can't focus same time, but you make it like you write in one textbox same time bind it in other textbox using jQuery or AngularJS.

Comment: You can do it without using jQuery or AngularJS (or Knockout or React or whatever)... it's just potentially a bit more work.

Answer (score 0):

I found http://codepen.io/keilin/pen/lCkap for css.

And added:

```
$("#left").on('keydown change', function(e) {
        $("#right").val($(this).val());
        console.log($("#right").val());
        $overlay.text($(this).val());
        var offset = $cursor.offset();
        var inputLeft = $(_this).offset().left;
        offset.left = Math.min($overlay.outerWidth(), $(_this).innerWidth() - 4);
        offset.left = inputLeft + Math.max(offset.left, 0);
        $cursor.offset(offset);
 });
```

If i understand correctly, you want something this: https://jsfiddle.net/8csab3t1/1/

ps: It's just an example. Please check with two chars.